# Where can I see how many Key Codes I have created?

Tags: destiny-2

*Season 14*

I can spend Ether on the Splicer Gauntlet to create Key Codes to open the chests in Override.

[image: Splicer Gauntlet]

However I have not found anywhere which tells me how many of these I have. With last seasons Hammer, it was slotted so you knew if you should do the seasonal activity or not.

This season I can't tell if I should do an Override or not because I don't know if I have a Key Code available to open the bonus Splicer chest at the end.

Can I see how many Key Codes I have in my inventory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the number of Key Codes you have is displayed on the quest item inside the quest inventory.

Here is an example

[image: Gauntlet with 2 key codes]

Here is the same, but after I crafted another Key Code

[image: Gauntlet with 3 key codes]

So the number of Key Codes is denoted by the filled yellow squares on the Gauntlet in your quest inventory.